# How to read and display SVG files in android

Tags: java, android, svg

while i am doing work on android apps i didnt find library files to read svg files and rendering those files. can any one post me some library files which supports svg.

thank you in advanced!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [link](https://answers.launchpad.net/libsvg-android/+question/115135) I bought from [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=android+render+svg). It mentions, that android doesn't have native svg support and refers to a library. Hope it helps!